# Number formula that will calculate days of purchase only if the checkbox returns a true value

Tags: formula, formula-field, checkbox

Hello I've been trying to create a formula that will calculate days since purchase date only when the checkbox approved is checked as true. I've tried the following in a number formula.

```
IF(
    Approvedcheck__c = True
) 
TODAY () - Sale_Date__c
```

I cannot find anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5) is a very good resource to reference.

From that, on the `IF()` function

> Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns a given value if true and another value if false.
> Use
>
> `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)` and replace logical_test with the expression you want evaluated; replace value_if_true with the value you want returned if the expression is true; replace value_if_false with the value you want returned if the expression is false.

All of those arguments are required, and the true/false results need to have the same type.

Also, `<boolean value> = true` can always be reduced to just `<boolean value>`. Likewise, `<boolean value> = false` can be reduced to just `NOT(<boolean value>)`

The general recommendation is to format formulas like code (one line only contains a single expression, indent an additional level after encountering an open parenthesis).

So what you're looking for is

```
IF(
    Approvedcheck__c,
    TODAY() - Sale_Date__c,
    /* The "else" value needs to be the same type, so we use 0 */
    0
)
```